Windows Task Scheduler Run User
We have created a scheduled task in Windows 2019 to cleanup IIS log files per the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage.
In order to avoid the use of SYSTEM we have created a local, limited privilege account that has modify permissions on the IIS log directory.
We have then configured the task to execute the script as this user. The task is configured with the below settings:

Run whether user is logged on or not
Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources.

The task appears to work as expected, but there are a few items we don't fully understand.
Questions:

Will the task cease execution when the local user's password expires, or will S4U continue to work?
Is this a smart way to execute the task? Most examples use the SYSTEM account which does not seem to be a secure way to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Most examples use the SYSTEM account which does not seem to be a secure way why is using system to purge log files insecure?

If somehow the script was compromised purposefully or accidentally it would run with all of the privileges of SYSTEM.

I don't think that's very compelling. The upshot here is you are trading that for a local account that will need to be managed. That includes the password, which will need to be rotated. I don't think you will experience the password expiration scenario outside the usual tests to validate (because you are rotating the password) , expiring it manually and/or testing it on an account allowed it to expire normally.

Probably worth noting it should be possible to purge logs without incurring the maintenance and liability of "yet another local account who thought it would be a good idea to create these?"

Lookup using and granting permissions to "NT Authority\LocalService" if you need a slightly less shiny object to use instead.
